# Loop pandas column and replace values

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have read many posts but not been successful. I have a column 'percent' that i wish to but in categories 1,2,3,4. the dataframe is called 'data' . I tried

```
for i in data.index:
    if i > 0.7:
        df.at[i,"percent"] =1
    if i <0.7 and i>0:
        df.at[i, "percent"] = 2
    if i <0 and i > -0.4:
        df.at[i, "percent"] = 3
    if i < 0.4:
        df.at[i, "percent"] = 4
```

but it looks like everything is replaced to 1. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I want to replace the value in the percent column, i.e if the value is 0.56, i want to replace it with 1

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.4,"x"],[0.5,"x"], [0.6,"y"], [0.7,"z"], [0.8,"z"]], columns=["pc","val"])

df['pc_quant'] =  np.digitize(df['pc'], [.4, .7])

print(df)
```

gives you:

```
    pc val  pc_quant
0  0.4   x         1
1  0.5   x         1
2  0.6   y         1
3  0.7   z         2
4  0.8   z         2
```

Comment: **TIL** `np.digitize`  This serves my usual purpose of `searchsorted`.  Thx

Comment: I dont understand at all

Comment: It seemed as though you were trying to quantize your input column into discrete values? Is the output not as expected?